# Defining dynamic table row color

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

First off, say this is my HTML:

```
<table class='tg'>
    <tr>
        <th class='tg-031e'>Column #1</th>
        <th class='tg-031e'>Column #2</th>
        <th class='tg-031e'>Column #3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='tg-031e'>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td class='tg-031e'>7</td>
        <td class='tg-031e'>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='tg-031e'>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td class='tg-031e'>12</td>
        <td class='tg-031e'>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='tg-031e'>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td class='tg-031e'>14</td>
        <td class='tg-031e'>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is set a CSS rule for a dynamic background color on the row containing a number higher than 5. For example, say the maximum limit is that of 20. For each number above 5, the color's opacity should gradually become higher (possibly via SCSS using `lighten()` and `darken()`). Here's a quick graphical representation:

[image]

So as shown above, I want this to apply for the whole `<tr>` and not just a single `<td>`. Here is **[a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wvwC/17/)** of what I have so far (without the lighten or darken of the color gradually).

Comment: CSS can not detect content...you need Javascript.

Comment: @Paulie_D: hence [tag:jquery], I'd imagine.

Comment: True, then some effort into self-solving would be appreciated...but the question asked for a **CSS rule**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternate approach:

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('tg-031e');

var scale=0;
for(var i = 4; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 153, 0," + scale + ")";
    scale+=.05;
}
```

No need to set a max value. This will work with an arbitrary number of table rows. After 25 rows, all rows just have the same/darkest background color. (This also prevents the background color from obscuring the text.)

Here's what it looks like on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/galeroy/9wo1z73r/5/)**.

Comment: Awesome! Even better one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest way I can think of: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5wvwC/20/)

```
$("tbody").find("tr").each(function() {
  var maxValue = 30;
  var sumCell = $(this).find('td.sum');
  var opacity = parseInt( sumCell.text() )/maxValue;
  if(sumCell.text() > 15) {
    sumCell.closest('tr').addClass('greenBg');
    sumCell.closest('tr').css('opacity',opacity);
  }
});
```

NOTE: Set the `maxValue` as per your requirements.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: That does it exactly how I want it to be. Thank you for your time :)